# CakePHP Add HTML in field options

Tags: cakephp

I try to recreate this menu in html to cakephp form, but i don't know how can i put the icon in the options...

```
<div class="ui fluid label dropdown">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <span class="default text">Filter by</span>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="0">With Comments<i class="comments right floated icon"></i></div>
        <div class="item" data-value="1">Without Comments<i class="comments outline right floated icon"></i></div>
        <div class="item" data-value="2">With Attachment<i class="attach right floated icon"></i></div>
        <div class="item" data-value="3">Without Attachment</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CakePHP code:

```
echo $this->Form->input('field',
        array(
           'options' => array('With Comments', 'Without Comments','Without Attachment'), 
           'empty' => 'Filter by', 
           'class' => 'ui dropdown', 
           'onchange' => 
           'submitForm()', 
           'name' => 'FB'));
```

Comment: Don't need to change your cakephp code, You should be use `style ` & `jquery ` to reform your `select option ` looks as per you  `HTML`.

Comment: I don't know if using `Form->input()` can work like this, as the structure is a bit more complex than a simple `<input type="text"/>` or `<select><option></option></select>` element.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to review the [FormHelper documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html) to verify you are properly using the helper.

> The select input type allows for a special $option attribute called 'escape' which accepts a bool and determines whether to HTML entity encode the contents of the select options. Defaults to true:

```php
$options = [
  'M' => 'Male <i class="fa fa-man"></i>',
  'F' => 'Female <i class="fa fa-woman"></i>'
];
echo $this->Form->select('gender', $options, ['escape' => false]);
```

*(Adapted from the documentation.)*